# How to use Botium Speech Processing with Botium Box (community edition) to test voice bot?

Tags: botium-box

I have insatlled Botium Box (community edition) v2.6.0 (running on port 4000) and Botium Speech Processing(running on port 81). I would like to test voice bot, So how to use above mentioned tool in integration to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only official Botium connector where Text-To-Speech and Speech-To-Text is needed is the *Alexa Voice Service Connector* (see [Github Repository](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-avs)). This connector works by exchanging audio files with the Alexa servers for simulating a real user interaction. You can configure Botium Speech Processing in the Connector Settings in Botium Box (or use the capabilities described in the Github repository when using it with Botium Core).

[image]